# pandas converting int or string to float

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to map two dataframes on the name to get the `id` of a student. The `id` returned has a decimal in it. For example, if the `id` in `name_to_id` is `12345`, the `id` in `student` becomes `12345.0`
Why is this decimal point getting added and how do I prevent it?

`students["id"] = students.name.map(name_to_id["id"])`

Comment: Can you post your `name_to_id` function? Also, an alternative approach (that may be more idiomatic to pandas) would be to left `merge `.

Comment: I would guess you want to specify `dtype={'id': str}` when you read the data in with whatever `pandas.read_` method you are using.

Comment: Also, you likely have a few rows with missing IDs? `NaN` is a float value, it cannot be stored in a typical `int` dtype. As a result, pandas upcasts the entire column to `float` so that it can store all values in a single reasonable (i.e. not object) dtype.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this for your students['id']

```
students.astype({'id': 'int32'}).dtypes
```

for your reference I found this on: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html